# Angular Router Hashing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I added `{useHash: true}` to my routes. Because of that, my link becomes `http://localhost:4200/#/employer`.

Then on my `<a>` tag, I added `[routerLink]="/details"`. It works perfectly fine when clicking the `<a>` tag because it redirects to my preferred component and url `http://localhost:4200/#/employer/details`. But, if I right click on it and open the link in new tab, the link becomes `http://localhost:4200/employer/details` emitting the `#` thus redirecting me to my PageNotFoundComponent.

Is there a way to add hash on `<a [routerLink]>`
so that if I right click the `<a>` tag, I will redirect to my preferred component?

Comment: I think the router link works well in angular, but The right-click searches for 'href', use developer options and check what is there in href of a.

Comment: if it didn't have #, then you should add a separate href like
<a [href] = "your URL/ # / {{ route path }} ">

Comment: The href doesn't have # on it

Comment: Try the method I said in 2nd comment.

Comment: Does this override [routerLink] of the anchor tag?